# How to select rows with multiple AND/OR statements in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following columns in my dataset:

```
.1. Goal
.2. Quarter
.3. Year
```

I have 4 Quarters: 1,2,3,4

I have 4 Years: 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018

I want to Select all Goals, except for 2019-QTR3 and 2019-QTR4

I've used Where statements, such as :

```
SELECT * from Table
WHERE 
(`Year` <> "2019" and `Quarter Name` <> "QTR3")
OR (`Year` <> "2019" and `Quarter Name` <> "QTR4")
```

But as a result, all rows with 2019 as year, or as QTR3 or QTR4 as quarter are not selected, which is not what I want

```
SELECT
* FROM Table

WHERE 
(`Year` <> "2019" and `Quarter Name` <> "QTR3")
OR (`Year` <> "2019" and `Quarter Name` <> "QTR4")
```

The results of my query do not include 2019 at all. They also don't include QTR3 and ATR4 at all (regardless of year). I don't want that

Comment: `I have 4 Quarters: 1,2,3,4` You should, but you don't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement is:

```
SELECT * from Table
WHERE 
NOT (`Year` = "2019" AND `Quarter Name` = "QTR3")
AND
NOT (`Year` = "2019" AND `Quarter Name` = "QTR4")
```

or with the IN operator:

```
SELECT * from Table
WHERE NOT (`Year` = "2019" AND `Quarter Name` IN ("QTR3", "QTR4"))
```

which is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * from Table
WHERE 
(`Year` <> "2019" OR `Quarter Name` <> "QTR3")
AND
(`Year` <> "2019" OR `Quarter Name` <> "QTR4")
```

or:

```
SELECT * from Table
WHERE (`Year` <> "2019" OR `Quarter Name` NOT IN ("QTR3", "QTR4"))
```

Comment: Could you please explain why my code was wrong. You did the same but with different operators

Comment: The logic is in my 1st query. You want rows that **don't have year 2019 and quarter qrt3** AND rows that **don't have year 2019 and quarter qrt4**. This is my 1st query and it can be written as the 3d if you know a little Boolean Algebra.

Comment: you are the GOAT

Answer (score 0):

> I want to Select all Goals, except for 2019-QTR3 and 2019-QTR4

You can use `NOT IN` with tuples:

```
SELECT * from `Table`
WHERE (`Year`, `Quarter Name`) NOT IN ( ('2019', 'QTR3'),  ('2019', 'QTR3'))
```

Answer (score -1):

if you do

```
SELECT * from Table WHERE Year <> "2019" or (Quarter Name <> "QTR3" AND Quarter Name <> "QTR4")
```

should work out for you. 
Edited

Comment: No, it's still kicking out all 2019 values. Although now it keeps QTR3 and QTR4 values

Comment: You need to replace `AND` to `OR` and `OR` to `AND` in this query.